# Super simple implementation of multiselect list box in Edit view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

Using MVC4 here with EF and CF (badly)

I have a class like this:

```
public class Feature
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }
}
```

And one like this:

```
public class Device   //change to Devices
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Feature> Features { get; set; }
}
```

On the Edit view for the Device model I would like for there to be a ListBox that contains all elements of the Feature model (Desc property displayed) with those features contained in the device.Features collection pre-selected.

Then, when the user clicks Save on the Edit view, the current collection of selected items in the ListBox gets written back to the device's Features collection.

What does the controller code and cshtml look like for this trick?

Thank you for your time,
Dave

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As always you could start by writing a view model that will meet the requirements of the view you described:

```
public class EditDeviceViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<int> SelectedFeatures { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Features { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and then your controller:

```
public class DeviceController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        Device device = (go get your device from your repository using the id)
        IList<Feature> features = (go get all features from your repository)

        // now build the view model
        var model = new EditDeviceViewModel();
        model.ID = device.ID;
        model.Name = device.Name;
        model.SelectedFeatures = device.Features.Select(x => x.ID);
        model.Features = features
            .Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = x.ID.ToString(),
                Text = x.Name,
            })
            .ToList();

        // pass the view model to the view
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(EditDeviceViewModel model)
    {
        // model.SelectedFeatures will contain the selected feature IDs here
        ...
    }
}
```

and finally the view:

```
@model EditDeviceViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ID)
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.SelectedFeatures)
        @Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.SelectedFeatures, Model.Features)
    </div>

    <button type="submit">Edit</button>
}
```

Comment: When I load the view, any features the device already has in its collection are not pre-selected in the list, and whenever I click on an item in the list I get a jScript error : Unhandled exception at line 1234, column 5 in http://localhost:52321/Scripts/jquery.validate.js  0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'call' of undefined or null reference

Comment: Yep, you are correct, I forgot the following in the controller action: `model.SelectedFeatures = device.Features.Select(x => x.ID);`. This is what will preselect the values present in the device. As far as the javascript error you are getting, well, that's something in your view, a code that you haven't shown, so I cannot read your mind and say why you might be getting this error. Maybe you have some javascript error somewhere or something.

Comment: I haven't done anything with jscript that I am aware of, this started off as a stock MVC4 VS-generated app. It throws that same error if I even try to scroll the list box. I see the items in box start to scroll just before VS breaks on the error.

Comment: Earlier in the life-cycle of this app I had been trying to apply Themeroller themes and apparently messed something up in jScript. I burned it to the ground and started clean and your solution works fine.  Thanks!

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - When I try to emulate this, my members of the posted model are null - ie model.SelectedFeatures is null. But, when I look at the Request.Params - all SelectedFeatures are returned there. Why wouldn't they be in my model?

Comment: Is it preferred to use IEnumerable instead of List ? Also is there advantage to use IList instead of List ?

Comment: What the hell does this mean? 'int' does not contain a definition for 'ID' and no extension method 'ID' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
This happens at x => x.ID