# How to multiselect ListBox asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, listbox

I have created a Listbox with `asp.net razor`. But i want to be able to multiselect the listbox. How do i do that?

I want to use something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult KenmerkSelectie(List<string> VarFromKenmerk1)
{

}
```

The following Listbox posts only one variable:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("KenmerkSelectie", "KenmerkSelectie", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "kenmerk1" }))
{
    @Html.ListBox("VarFromKenmerk1", (SelectList)ViewBag.var)
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
}
```

**Edit:**
I'm trying the following code but I get a error:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("KenmerkSelectie", "KenmerkSelectie", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "kenmerk1" }))
{
    @Html.ListBoxFor("VarFromKenmerkTEST",(MultiSelectList)ViewBag.var), new {@style = "width: 252px; height: 300px;"}) 
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
}


public ActionResult index()
{
    ViewBag.VarFromKenmerk1 = new List<SelectListItem>();
    ViewBag.VarFromKenmerk1.Add(new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = "House",
        Text = "House"
    });

    ViewBag.VarFromKenmerkTEST = new MultiSelectList(ViewBag.VarFromKenmerk1);
    return View();
}


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult KenmerkSelectie(List<string> VarFromKenmerkTEST){
    foreach(var ken in VarFromKenmerkTEST){
        //selected items
    }
}
```

> Compiler Error Message: CS0411: The type arguments for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.ListBoxFor(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)'
>   cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly.
>
> Source Error:
>   @Html.ListBoxFor("VarFromKenmerkTEST",(MultiSelectList)ViewBag.var),
>   new {@style = "width: 252px; height: 300px;"})

and I don't know if parameter in KenmerkSelectie is good.

Comment: What do you mean it _"post only 1 variable"_? It will post back an array of values that will be bound to your parameter on post back (if you select 3 options, then `VarFromKenmerk1` will contain 3 values)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Super simple implementation of multiselect list box in Edit view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18363158/super-simple-implementation-of-multiselect-list-box-in-edit-view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a viewModel to pass the data to your view (strongly typed) and then create your listbox with

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(viewmodel => viewmodel.model.property, viewmodel.data )
```

the data attribute of the viewmodel should be a [Multiselectlist](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.multiselectlist%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

viewmodel:

```
public class viewModel
{
    public MultiSelectList data { get; set; }

    public Model model { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to use a model... is it not possible with ListBox

Comment: you could just put a multiSelectList in the viewbag

Comment: See this link, https://dotnetfiddle.net/d9C3LX
when using the Viewbag, you cannot use Html.Listboxfor

Answer (score 0):

You need to set Selected property of SelectList class as well as add attribute new {Multiple = "multiple"}

```
@{
    var VarFromKenmerk1= new List<SelectList> { 
        new SelectList{ Text = "Text1", Value = "Value1", Selected = true },
        new SelectList { Text = "Text2", Value = "Value2" },
        new SelectList { Text = "Text3", Value = "Value3", Selected = true }
    };
}

@Html.ListBox("VarFromKenmerk1", VarFromKenmerk1, new {Multiple = "multiple"})
```

Comment: The `@Html.ListBox()` and `@Html.ListBoxFor()` helpers do add the `multiple="multiple"` attribute