# Bindig ListBox selection to model properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, listbox

I've been struggling to bind a MultiSelectList from Html helper to a specific model.

**Model**
In my model I have something like this:

```
public class DefaultSelection
{
    public SelectionItem Selection1 {get;set;}
    public SelectionItem Selection2 {get;set;}
    public SelectionItem Selection3 {get;set;}

    public IEnumerable<SelectionItem> Items{get;set;}

    public DefaultSelection()
    {
        Selection1 = new SelectionItem(true, "Item1");
        Selection2 = new SelectionItem(false, "Item2");
        Selection3 = new SelectionItem(true, "Item3");
        Items = new List<SelectionItem>(new SelectionItem[]
                                        {Selection1,Selection2,Selection3});
    }
}

public class SelectionItem
{
    public bool Selected {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}

    public SelectionItem(bool selected, string name)
    {
        Selected = selected;
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

What I want to do is binding my ListBox selection to *Selected* property of a *SelectionItem*.
I've tried this in my View:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.Items, new MultiSelectList( Model.Items, Model.Items.Where(item => item.Selected)), new { @class = "selectpicker" })
```

Unfortunatly neither the selected items are shown properly (nothing is selected) nor has a selection any effects on the model...

Is there a way to solve this?
Can I get rid of this *Items* property for it is just a reference to the needed properties?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/18363359/4868839

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Super simple implementation of multiselect list box in Edit view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18363158/super-simple-implementation-of-multiselect-list-box-in-edit-view)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a lot easier than you think. Let's give this a try.

> Create a good view model:

```
public class DefaultSelection
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Items { get; set; }

    //Set a property to hold the selected items IDs.
    public IEnumerable<string> SelectedItems { get; set; }

    public DefaultSelection()
    {
        //preselected features
        Items = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Item1", Selected = true},
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Item2", Selected = false},
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Item3", Selected = true}
        };
    }
}
```

> Render the ListBox in the view:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Items)
    @Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.SelectedItems, Model.Items, new { @class = "selectpicker" })
</div>
```

Note that I'm using here the built-in `System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem` class instead of your custom one `SelectionItem`- you can safely get rid of it.

Now you'll get the selected items id's (in this case the name, because you didn't specify value property when create the items) in your model after posting.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Worked fine for me! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

your `@Html.ListBoxFor` should be like this

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedNames, new MultiSelectList(Model.Items,"Name", "Name",Model.Items.Where(x=>x.Selected).Select(x=>x.Name)), new { @class = "selectpicker" })
```

you have to specify `Value field` and `Text field` of `Model.Items` which is `"Name", "Name"` and `Model.Items.Where(x=>x.Selected).Select(x=>x.Name)` will select all the values where selected is `true` but your model will return the values in list of string so you should define a field

```
public List<string> SelectedNames { get; set; }
```

where you will get the values of the selected items